# Give a link to a class after clicking on a button in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i am working with react, and i have actually 3 classes in 3 files. the App.js containes a navbar and a button after clicking on that button a table will appear from 'Table.js', but i added other buttoms in front of each row of table so when i click on that button i want to be redirectionned to another class which is offer.js that shows results from database. as i am using a map inside Table.js i don't how to exactly do that linking.

```js
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {
  Container, Col, Form,
  FormGroup, Label, Input,
  Button, Dropdown, 
} from 'reactstrap';
import Axios from "axios";
import './App.css';
import Table from './Table';

class App extends Component {

  state= { render: false }
  add = () => {
    this.setState({render : !this.state.render})
  }
   render(){
  
    return (
        <div>
     <nav className="box"> 
           
          <div className="element sourcedropdown" >
            <label>Source :</label>
            <select className="form-control" name="Sources" onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <option selected>Select Source</option>
              <option value="1">Welcome To The Jungle</option>
              <option value="2">Indeed</option>
              <option value="3">Angellist</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="element Techdropdown">
            <label>Technology :</label>
            <select className="form-control" name="Tech"  onChange= {this.handleChange}>
              <option selected>Select Technology</option>
              <option className="dropdown-item" value="1">React</option>
              <option className="dropdown-item" value="2">Node</option>
              <option className="dropdown-item" value="3">Angular</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          
          
          <div id="contrat" className="element contrat">
          <label>Contract :</label>
            <select className="form-control" name="Tech"  onChange= {this.handleChange}>
              <option selected>Select contract</option>
              <option className="dropdown-item" value="1">CDD</option>
              <option className="dropdown-item" value="2">CDI</option>
              <option className="dropdown-item" value="3">Stage</option>
              <option className="dropdown-item" value="3">Alternance</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div id="checkbox" className ="element checkbox">
          <label check>
          <input type="checkbox"  onChange= {this.handleChange} />{' '}
          Remote
         </label>
          </div> //here i am colling a table from Table.js
           <Button id="button" onClick={() => this.add()}>CLICK</Button>
     
          </nav>    
          <p>'   '</p>
          { this.state.render &&
        <Table/>
     }
    
        </div>
         
      
    );
   }
}

export default App;
```

```js
import Axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Table.css'
import OFFRE from './offres'
import {
   Container, Col, Form,
   FormGroup, Label, Input,
   Button, Dropdown, 
 } from 'reactstrap';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom"
class Table extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props) 
      this.state = { 
         Offers: [
            {  name: 'clx', website: 19},
            {  name: 'AMAZON', website: 25 },
           
            { name: 'Spotify', website: 16},
            { name: 'Microsoft', website: 25},
         ],
       
      }
   }
  
 
   useEffect(){
      Axios.get('http:localhost:3001/api/offre').then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
      });
   }

   renderTableHeader() {
    let header = Object.keys(this.state.Offers[0])
    return header.map((key, index) => {
       return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
    })
 }
renderTableData() {
    return this.state.Offers.map((offer, index) => {
       const {  name, website} = offer
       return (
          <tr >
            
             <td className="name">{name}</td>
             <td>{website}</td>
       
 // here where i want to call a table from offre.js and each row the link differ because of "name"
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-info">Button</button>
   
         
          </tr>
          
       )
       
    })
 }

 render() {
    return (
       <div >
          <h1 id='title'>Start-ups List Table</h1>
          <table id='offers'>
             <tbody>
             
                <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
                  {this.renderTableData()}
                  
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </div>
    )
 }

}
export default Table
```

Comment: So when you click on the button of each row you need to go to the offer.js page. If thats the case when you are looping and returning each tr on td of each button add a id of the product, so when the user clicks on it you can get that id and pass on the url params and pass to the offer page, from offer page you can take from url params and call the api for getting the offers related to the product, So when you are using in url params, later for refreshing it will be helpful, If this is what you are expecting let me know will add the code for the same

Comment: Hello, Yess!! that's exactly what i need

Comment: @ LlMm, i have added the answer with a working code snippet, Kindly check if it helped you kindly please vote and accept it so it will be helpful for others

Comment: @ LlMm kindly check the answer and let me know if it helped you or not

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this one. I have created the flow with mock data. Hope this will give you a better understanding.

**Routes.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Product from "./Product";

const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <App />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/product/:id">
        <Product />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Table from "./Table";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const columns = [
  { property: "id", header: "Id" },
  { property: "title", header: "Title" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [showTable, setShowTable] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleSetShowTable = () => setShowTable(!showTable);

  const handleProductDetail = (datumn) => {
    history.push(`/product/id=${datumn.id}`, { datumn });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleSetShowTable}>Show Table</button>
      {showTable && (
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          handleProductDetail={handleProductDetail}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Table.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Table = (props) => {
  const { columns, data, handleProductDetail } = props;
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {columns.map((col) => (
            <th key={col.header}>{col.header}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((datumn) => {
          return (
            <tr key={datumn.id} onClick={() => handleProductDetail(datumn)}>
              {columns.map((col, index) => {
                return (
                  <td key={`${col.property}-${index}`}>
                    {datumn[col.property]}
                  </td>
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

**Product.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Product = (props) => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleBackClick = () => history.goBack();
  return (
    <div>
      {state?.datumn && (
        <Fragment>
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>{state.datumn.title}</p>
          <hr />
          <h3>Body</h3>
          <p>{state.datumn.body}</p>

          <button onClick={handleBackClick}>Go Back</button>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-blackwell-ufe2o)